# What's wrong with this example of Java property inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

### Inheritance.java

```
public class InheritanceExample {
  static public void main(String[] args){
    Cat c = new Cat();
    System.out.println(c.speak());

    Dog d = new Dog();
    System.out.println(d.speak());
  }
}
```

### Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
  protected String sound;
  public String speak(){
    return sound;
  }
}
```

### Cat.java

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
  protected String sound = "meow";
}
```

### Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  protected String sound = "woof";
}
```

---

### Output:

```
null
null
```

My animals cannot speak. So sad.

Comment: I feel bad for upvoting just for the last sentence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fields aren't polymorphic. You've declared three entirely distinct fields... the ones in `Cat` and `Dog` *shadow* or *hide* the one in `Animal`.

The simplest (but not necessarily best) way of getting your current code is to remove `sound` from `Cat` and `Dog`, and set the value of the *inherited* `sound` field in the constructor for `Cat` and `Dog`.

A better approach would be to make `Animal` abstract, and give it a protected constructor which takes the sound... the constructors of `Cat` and `Dog` would then call `super("meow")` and `super("woof")` respectively:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private final String sound;

    protected Animal(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    public String speak(){
        return sound;
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        super("meow");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super("woof");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what's the **best** way? (You made me ask).

Comment: @macek: I was getting there... just typing as quickly as I could :)

Comment: what if I have several fields to populate. Surely I wouldn't want a rigid constructor that takes a variable for each field... right?

Comment: Phew! You made it within that 5-minute window! (Once again.)

Comment: @macek: That really depends. Maybe you'll set everything in the constructor, or maybe it's appropriate to have `setFoo` methods... it partly depends on whether you're aiming for immutability. Another option is overriding methods in the subclasses. It all depends :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override class fields, only methods. The `sound` field in your `Dog` and `Cat` classes is actually *hiding* the `sound` field in the `Animal` superclass.

You can, however, access superclass fields from subclasses, so you could do something like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog() {
    sound = "woof";
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat() {
    sound = "meow";
  }
}
```

Or, you can make the `Animal` class abstract, and declare the `speak` method abstract too, then define it in subclasses:

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public abstract String speak();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public String speak {
    return "woof";
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public String speak {
    return "meow";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding fields. The `sound` in `Animal` is not the same `String`  as the `sound` in `Cat`.

One possible solution is to create a constructor and there simply say

```
super.sound = "meow";
```

instead of in the class body saying

```
protected String sound = "meow";
```

to set the field.

Answer (score 0):

A method will look in its own class' namespace to resolve fields. While methods defined in sub-classes can look up the hierarchy to resolve fields, the same is not true for classes defined higher up in the hierarchy, i.e., super-classes won't look down the hierarchy to resolve fields [and their values]

Answer (score 0):

You're [shadowing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#34133) the field inherited from `Animal`. You have a few options, but the prettiest way of doing it is passing the sound in the constructor:

```
public class Animal {
  private final String sound;
  protected Animal(String sound){
    if (sound == null)
      throw new NullPointerException("sound");
    this.sound = sound;
  }
  public String speak(){
    return sound;
  }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat(){ super("meow"); }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog(){ super("woof"); }
}
```

This way, you can make sure that an `Animal` always has a valid sound, right from construction.

Answer (score 0):

The Java(TM) way is to declare the protected String getSound() in Animal.java and implement it in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allow your animals to speak!
you should do like this :

Cat.java:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
//  protected String sound = "meow";

    public Cat(){
        this.sound = "cat";
    }

}
```

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
// protected String sound = "woof";

    public Dog(){
        this.sound = "dog";
    }
}
```

just because there are two members "sound" in Cat or Dog,and the one inherited from Animal
is hidden without value(so it prints null);another is special to Cat or Dog,which is assigned a value.
So you should  use the pointer 'this' to quote the original member 'sound'.