# Java Inheritance and this keyword

Tags: java, this, keyword

look at this code

```
public class Machine {
    public String name = "Machine";
    public static int j = 5;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Machine is running");
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }

    public void run2() {
        System.out.println("Machine is running");

        System.out.println(this.name);
        this.run();
    }
}

public class Computer extends Machine {
    String name = "Computer ";

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Computer is running");
    }
}

public class Cpu extends Computer {
    public String name = "Cpu ";

    public Cpu() {
        System.out.println("Constructor of cpu");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Constructor cpu is running");
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public void getComputerName() {
        System.out.println(super.name + " Really?");
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cpu c = new Cpu();
        c.run2();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Constructor of cpu
Machine is running
Machine
Constructor cpu is running
Cpu@1db9742
```

My question is why when we using `this` keyword with function, it goes to where `this` refers and active the function, but when we use it with field it just go with field of the current class? like in the example

Comment: Just read this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879343/225503). Fields are not inherited

Comment: What a confusing example..

Comment: @DiegoFreniche Fields are not polymorphic, but they are inherited (how else inherited getters and setters of private field would work?). They may not be accessible (like private fields) but they are there.

Comment: It helps if you use `@Override` annotation when you override things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override variables, only methods. You are creating a new variable in `CPU` which contains the value, not overriding the value specified in the superclass.

---

Not related to the problem, but:

`CPU` shouldn't extend `Computer`, since a `CPU` is not a `Computer`. Use the 'is-a' trick to determine whether you should extend. A `Computer` 'has-a' `CPU`, so composition should be used.

Comment: But how i can't override variables, isn't the variable name is overriden? or it do that because its on its scope?

Comment: @Saif That's just how inheritence works. You can only override methods, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you are exeucting run2 method for Cpu, the parent method in Machine is called because it is not overriden in Cpu. In that scope, this.name refers to Machine's field.

When run2() in Machine calls this.run(), it calls it on the object which is being executed - Cpu. Cpu overrides run(), and so that method is called. Inside Cpu.run's scope, the field name is that of the Cpu class. "this" refers to the Cpu class as well.