# Could you please analyze the output of that JAVA code about inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have add my question in the comment of the code.

```
class Parent{
    int num =9; //I think num in Parent class is overrided by the num in Child class. why is the num in the first line of output is still 9?
    { //code block
        System.out.println("Parent constructor code..."+num);
    }

    Parent(){
        System.out.println("Parent constructor run"); 
        show(); //why does this method here invoke the show() method in Child class?
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("Parent show..."+num);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    int num = 8; 
    {
        System.out.println("Child constructor code..."+num);
        num = 10;
    }

    Child(){ 
        System.out.println("Child constructor run"); 
        show(); 
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("Child show..."+num);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }

}
```

the output is:

> Parent constructor code...9
>   Parent constructor run
>   Child show...0
>   Child constructor code...8
>   Child constructor run
>   Child show...10

thank you guys! I have figured out that it's a variable shadowing and hiding problem.

Comment: It invokes the overridden Child class version, because you are actually instantiating Child, not Parent

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879338/whats-wrong-with-this-example-of-java-property-inheritance

Comment: "I think num in Parent class is overrided by the num in Child class." - your thinking is wrong, fields can't be overridden, only method can. Defining a field with the same name in a subclass merely shadows the field from the superclass.

Comment: Please remember to upvote helpful answers, and accept an answer if it solves your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of object construction is:

1. variable declaration and initialization
2. instance constructor block
3. constructor

If a class has a parent class, the same order is done for the parent *before it is for actual class*.

**parent first**

> int num = 9

is evaluated first, `num` is set to 9 (parent's 1.)

> Parent constructor code...9

Instance initializer blocks are executed before a constructor (parent's 2.)

> Parent constructor run

The constructor is called (parent's 3.)

> Child show...0

The constructor of `Parent` calls `show()`. `show()` is overridden, therefore `Child`'s is called.

Child's 1. and 2. have not been called yet, therefore the overriding `num` in `Child` is still 0. *1

**then the child**

> int num = 8

`Child`'s 1. is evaluated

> Child constructor code...8

`Child`'s 2. `num` is set to 10 after this.

> Child constructor run

`Child`'s 3.

> Child show...10

`Child`'s constructor calling `show()`.

*1:

This is why calling non-`final` methods in a constructor is very dangerous. Methods tend to rely on a member variable being initialized; they are not at this point.

Were this a non-primitive variable, you might very well run into a `NullPointerException` if your method tries to access it.

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When java creates a child class, [it has to call `super()` to initialize the parent class](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/what-are-the-frequently-asked-questions-about-constructors-in-java/) - this is so it can instantiate private fields in the super class, or other activities. (This does not create an object of the parent class.) That's why you see `Parent constructor code...9` - it's calling the parent code, and printing the parent's `num`.

Because you create a child class, the child's `show()` is called *in the parent constructor*. This is why [it's dangerous to call non-final methods in a constructor](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JAVA/Non-final+method+invocation+in+constructor) - if a child overrides them, the child's methods will be called instead.

The child's `num` is 0 because [Java initializes member variables to default values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560704/7431860), and your code hasn't yet had a chance to set it to 10.

As for your child code, [the `num` is not being overridden, it is being *hidden*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parent-and-child-classes-having-same-data-member-in-java/) - only methods can be overridden. That's why your child's `show()` displays it as 10, once it's properly initialized. If you want to access the parent's variable, you can do this with `super.num`, but this is often regarded as bad practice, since it can cause confusion.

Comment: "I'm not sure why it calls the child's show(), nor am I sure why the child's num is 0 - num is uninitialized at that point." > There is no such thing as "uninitialized" for class fields - they are all set to 0 before the constructor is run.

Comment: Sure enough, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560704/7431860) explained it to me well. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Learning something new every day - thank you!

Comment: Also: "I'm not sure why it calls the child's show()," Because you have an instance of child, and so the child's method will be called.

Comment: Does that mean that even though the parent constructor is called, the child's method overrides the `show()` call in the super constructor?

Comment: Yes. Thats why it is very dangerous to call non-final methods within a constructor.

Comment: Edited to reflect that, I think I learned more from answering this question than I would've if I had asked it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because automatically your constructor call super class constructor. ( for our first question. ) nevertheless, you override show so when it meets this method, it call the child method